# Is there any good reason for AS3 not to throw an exception when trying to operate on NaN?

Tags: actionscript-3, nan

When is an operation on a NaN variable valid? I would say never.

Yet in AS3 no exception is thrown and the default of 0 is returned when a operation is attempted on such a variable.

Why doesn't AS3 throw an exception here?

Comment: FWIW operations are always valid on NaN in Java, and do not throw exceptions. They always result in NaN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No exception is thrown in AS3 when dealing with `NaN` because AS3 is a dialect of [ECMAScript](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf&pli=1), which in turn implements [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), which defines the bahavior of `NaN`. This standard is implemented in a bunch of languages and architectures, including ones that do not have robust exception handling. `NaN` represents a way to express these values without requiring exceptions, in a way that is well understood and well documented across a bunch of platforms and languages.

If it wasn't implemented against the standard, then I would be willing to wager there would be people here asking "Why does AS3 throw and exception rather than returning `NaN` like every other IEEE 754 floating point implementation does?!"

See "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic...](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#899)" for a quick overview on floating point math and `NaN` in general, and check out the [wikipedia on NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), and you'll see there are actually two types of NaN defined by the standard. A quiet NaN and a signaling NaN.

> When is an operation on a NaN variable valid? I would say never.

No offense intended, I don't think that you are in the best position to make that absolute statement, because honestly, a lot of people a lot smarter than you in their profession thought about it and didn't come to the same conclusion.

Comment: The personal attack wasn't necessary but thanks; this was the sort of answer I was looking for.

Comment: It wasn't a personal attack, but a sort of platonic statement of fact. The first step in learning is admitting you don't know everything. If you had not made your first assumption that it's never valid to operate on a NaN, then who knows? You might have found these links, and others on your own. But at least you asked somebody, and it wasn't meant as an insult, unless you really do think of yourself as one of the greatest minds on the planet right now. I know I'm not and I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is for optimization purposes. If Flash had to check every value at runtime, any math operation would be very slow. When there's a chance that a value might be NaN, you just need to check it yourself using `isNaN`.

Comment: I know. The question is - Why is it this way?

Comment: @JonoRR, optimization : means to allow the code to run faster. =)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug.

The `int` and `uint` in flash by default is 0.

Try all of these variations:

```
var scale:Number;
var resultINT:int = undefined; // still 0 in the output;
var resultNUMBER:Number; // is NaN;
var resultUINT:uint;// sezo by default

trace ( this, scale, resultINT, resultNUMBER, resultUINT );
```

Comment: I'm going to reword the question. Looks like people are focusing more on the example.

Comment: if you setting a `int` or `uint` to `undefined` or it is `NaN` it still wil be 0.